# getopt_long_only segmentation fault

Tags: linux, command-line, getopt

I'm trying to use getopt_long_only to parse a command line.  My app reads a handful of command line options.

E.g.  "app --alpha=1 --beta=2 --cecil=3"

getopt_long_only works fine as expected as long as valid command line parameters are passed in.  But if you invoke the app with an invalid "single dashed" option at the end and at other inappropriate places, a seg fault crash occurs.  What's going on here?  Seems like getopt_long_only isn't being resilient to mistyped arguments.  Or am I invoking the function wrong?

Example:

```
> ./app --beta=1 -?
starting
index = 1   ret=0  optarg=1
Segmentation fault
```

Code below (C++: app.cc)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <getopt.h>

void ProcessCommandLineArgs(int argc, char** argv)
{

    option longopts[] = {
        {"alpha", optional_argument, 0, 0},
        {"beta",  optional_argument, 0, 0},
        {"cecil", optional_argument, 0, 0}
    };

    int index;
    int ret;
    bool fParseError = false;

    while (true)
    {
        ret = ::getopt_long_only(argc, argv, "", longopts, &index);

        if (ret < 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        if ((ret == '?') || (ret == ':'))
        {
            fParseError = true;
            break;
        }

        printf("index = %d   ret=%d  optarg=%s\n", index, ret, optarg?optarg:"<null>");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("starting\n");
    ProcessCommandLineArgs(argc, argv);
    printf("exiting\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does it still crash if you change `int index;` to `int index = 0`;?

Comment: Thanks 1of1.  It indeed did stop crashing when I did that.  Which makes no sense.... so I took a deeper dive at the man page.  That led me to discover that I was forgetting to properly null terminate the last row in the array.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found the problem.

I was forgetting to have a "zero-row" at the end of my option array declaration.

```
option longopts[] = {
    {"alpha", optional_argument, 0, 0},
    {"beta",  optional_argument, 0, 0},
    {"cecil", optional_argument, 0, 0},
    {NULL, 0, 0, 0}
};
```